# StorybookJS: Accessing non-existent addons channel

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I am currently trying to add the `@storybook/addon-console` to Storybook.

After running `npm install @storybook/addon-console @storybook/addon-actions --save-dev`, I get this error when I try to run `npm run storybook`:

```
Error: Accessing non-existent addons channel, see https://storybook.js.org/basics/faq/#why-is-there-no-addons-channel
    at AddonStore.getChannel (/Users/mitchell/Documents/GitHub/TapTapesWeb/node_modules/@storybook/addons/dist/cjs/index.js:53:13)
```

I tried to add this to my config.js file as per that link, to no avail:

```
import addons, { mockChannel } from '@storybook/addons';

addons.setChannel(mockChannel());
```

This is my Storybook `main.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    stories: ['../components/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
    addons: [
        '@storybook/addon-links',
        '@storybook/addon-essentials',
        'storybook-addon-material-ui',
        '@storybook/addon-postcss',
        '@storybook/addon-console',
        '@storybook/addon-actions'
    ],
    reactOptions: {
        fastRefresh: true
    }
};
```

Here is my Storybook `config.js` file:

```
import theme, { muiTheme } from '../constants/theme';
import React from 'react';
import { MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';

export const decorators = [
    (Story) => (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <MuiThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
                {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
                <CssBaseline />
                <Story />
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
    )
];
```

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "TapTapesWeb",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "test": "jest --passWithNoTests",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix .",
    "format": "prettier --write './**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,css,md,json}' --config ./.prettierrc",
    "postinstall": "husky install",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.34",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "next": "10.0.7",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-horizontal-scrolling-menu": "^0.7.10",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.1",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.2.0-beta.5",
    "@storybook/addon-console": "^1.2.3",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.2.0-beta.5",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.2.0-beta.5",
    "@storybook/addon-postcss": "^2.0.0",
    "@storybook/addon-viewport": "^6.2.0-beta.5",
    "@storybook/addons": "^6.2.0-beta.5",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.2.0-beta.5",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.12.0",
    "eslint": "^7.20.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^7.0.0",
    "husky": "^5.1.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "storybook-addon-material-ui": "^0.9.0-alpha.24",
    "storybook-addon-state": "^1.0.3"
  }
}
```